# Longest common subsequence using Dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement the code of the longest common subsequence(LCS) using Dynamic Programming. I have chosen two strings "abcdef" and "abcdfe".The answer should be 6 but I am getting 5.I have checked the code and algorithm several times.
Below is the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int max(int a,int b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}

void c(){
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

#endif // ONLINE_JUDGE

}

int main() {
c();
string str1="abcdef",str2="abcdfe";
int n=str1.length(),m=str2.length();
int t[n+1][m+1];
for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m+1;j++){
         t[i][j]=0;
    }
}
for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<m+1;j++){
        if(str1[i-1]==str2[j-1]){
            t[i][j]=1+t[i-1][j-1];
        }
        else{
            t[i][j]=max(t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m+1;j++){
        cout<<t[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should the answer be 6?

Comment: isn't it 4? :-)

Comment: @anatolyg because string 1 has all characters that string 2 has and that is 6 characters.

Comment: @Klaus that is for the longest common substring here we want to find out the longest common subsequence.

Comment: I am looking at [this](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/longest-common-subsequence) description of the Longest Common Subsequence (LCS). If I understand it properly then you are getting the correct answer because the symbols have to be in the same order in both sequences. Therefore, if string 2 was "abcdfef" then you ought to get 6 as the answer.